# How are system admins deploying software across a network for OSX?

Tags: mac-osx, rpc

I'm looking for a solution for Mac that allows remote silent installs of software.  I'm a system administrator that works for a company that has a network of both Mac and Windows computers.  On the Windows side we can use a technology called Remote Procedure Call (RPC) to do this.

Is anyone in the Mac community doing this, and if so what technologies are you employing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you mean by RPC as the normal meaning is for how a program on one machine calls a function on another and not how to install software

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a cluster of Mac computers with same configuration/applications?](http://serverfault.com/questions/171994/setting-up-a-cluster-of-mac-computers-with-same-configuration-applications)

Answer (score 3):

[Apple Remote Desktop (ARD)](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) can do this -- if the other computer is on and you can connect to it.  [There is a possibility to run something called a Task Server, but I've never tried it.]

We are using a product called [Casper](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite) that helps tremendously in doing this.

I have wondered about using [Munki](http://code.google.com/p/munki/), [Puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Puppet_Mac_Osx), and [Radmind](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/radmind/) but haven't tried them.

Comment: If you have the package already ARD is your best bet but if you're going to develop them from scratch, I'm a big supporter of Radmind.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we use [Absolute Manage](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/absolute-manage/features.aspx) to do this. The product is full of other features, and not cheap. Check the link for more.